# TradingView Pine editor getting the actual price of a label

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the actual price of a label when it was triggered.   I tried a few ways but I'm not able to.  Any help would be appreciated.
I'm attaching the whole code here now.  Maybe you can have a look at it and see where I went wrong.  Thank you for all the help.

```
//@version=4
study("buy/sell", overlay=true)

//Gathers User Inputs
bsSignals = input(true, "Buy & Sell Signals On / Off")

n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")

t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realC = security(t, timeframe.period, close)

//WaveTrend for Signals
ap = src
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
wt1 = tci

wt2 = sma(wt1,4)

// Defines Variables for Avoiding Duplicate Signals
var sell = false
var buy = false

// Defines Trade Signals
buySignal = not sell and crossover(wt1, wt2)
sellSignal = not buy and crossunder(wt1, wt2)

if buySignal
    sell := true
    buy := false

if sellSignal
    sell := false
    buy := true

// Plots Signals to Chart
plotshape(bsSignals ? buySignal : na, title = "Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.labelup, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, text = "BUY")
plotshape(bsSignals ? sellSignal : na, title = "Sell Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, text = "SELL")

// Alert Conditions
alertcondition(buySignal, "Buy Signal", "Buy Signal")
alertcondition(sellSignal, "Sell Signal", "Sell Signal")

var label longCondLabel = na
var label shortCondLabel = na

if (buySignal) 
    longCondLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=realC, color=color.new(#1E90FF, 0),
         style=label.style_labeldown, size=size.auto)
    label.delete(id=longCondLabel[1])

if (sellSignal)
    shortCondLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=realC, color=color.new(#FF1493, 0),
         style=label.style_labelup, size=size.auto)
    label.delete(id=shortCondLabel[1])
// Plot all label prices on the chart
plot(series=buySignal ? label.get_y(id=longCondLabel) : na,
     color=color.new(#1E90FF, 0), linewidth=4,
     style=plot.style_circles, title="New Buy")

plot(series=sellSignal ? label.get_y(id=shortCondLabel) : na,
     color=color.new(#FF1493, 0), linewidth=4,
     style=plot.style_circles, title="New Sell")
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my head around what to put in the +tostring()
Line 59 and 71.

So I put in wt1 in one and close in the other. As you use the source hlc3 the signal I believe would not fire until the candle is closed making the hlc3 complete.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Frien_dd

//@version=4
study("buy/sell", overlay=true)

//Gathers User Inputs
bsSignals = input(true, "Buy & Sell Signals On / Off")

n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")

t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realC = security(t, timeframe.period, close)

//WaveTrend for Signals
ap = src
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
wt1 = tci

wt2 = sma(wt1,4)


// Defines Variables for Avoiding Duplicate Signals
var sell = false
var buy = false

// Defines Trade Signals
buySignal = not sell and crossover(wt1, wt2)
sellSignal = not buy and crossunder(wt1, wt2)

if buySignal
    sell := true
    buy := false

if sellSignal
    sell := false
    buy := true

// Plots Signals to Chart
//plotshape(bsSignals ? buySignal : na, title = "Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.labelup, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, text = "BUY")
//plotshape(bsSignals ? sellSignal : na, title = "Sell Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, text = "SELL")

// Long Label

var longLabel = label.new(x=na, y=na, yloc=yloc.abovebar,
     color=color.green, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0),
     size=size.normal, style=label.style_labeldown)
     
if bsSignals ? buySignal : na

    // Long
    longLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=na, yloc=yloc.abovebar,
         style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.new(color.green, 0),
         text="Buy - "+tostring(wt1), textcolor=color.white)     

// Short Label
var shortLabel = label.new(x=na, y=na, yloc=yloc.belowbar,
     color=color.red, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0),
     size=size.normal, style=label.style_labelup)

if bsSignals ? sellSignal : na

    // Short
    shortLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=na, yloc=yloc.abovebar,
         style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.new(color.red, 0),
         text="Sell - "+tostring(hlc3), textcolor=color.white)


// Alert Conditions
alertcondition(buySignal, "Buy Signal", "Buy Signal")
alertcondition(sellSignal, "Sell Signal", "Sell Signal")

var label longCondLabel = na
var label shortCondLabel = na

if (buySignal) 
    longCondLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=realC, color=color.new(#1E90FF, 0),
         style=label.style_labeldown, size=size.auto)
    label.delete(id=longCondLabel[1])

if (sellSignal)
    shortCondLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=realC, color=color.new(#FF1493, 0),
         style=label.style_labelup, size=size.auto)
    label.delete(id=shortCondLabel[1])
// Plot all label prices on the chart
plot(series=buySignal ? label.get_y(id=longCondLabel) : na,
     color=color.new(#1E90FF, 0), linewidth=4,
     style=plot.style_circles, title="New Buy")

plot(series=sellSignal ? label.get_y(id=shortCondLabel) : na,
     color=color.new(#FF1493, 0), linewidth=4,
     style=plot.style_circles, title="New Sell")
```

Comment: I pasted the code I'm trying above.  It plots a dot when it receives a longCond or shortCond.  I want the dot to be plotted in the candle at the exact price when it receives the signal.

Comment: Have read through here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html to get the price you need to include -    text = PriceLocation+"dOpen - "+tostring(dOpen)    -. If you had added the working (full) code I could have copied and pasted it and changed it to confirm it.

Comment: I was able to paste the whole code for you.  I would appreciate your help.  Thank you

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the whole code?  Thank you for your time

Comment: Apologies I will have a look at UTC1800 today to see if I can help.

Comment: Have a look at what I have put above.

Comment: Awesome!!  Thank you.   Another issue I'm having that you might know, is that sometimes I get a Buy or Sell label that gets added and a few seconds later it  gets deleted.   Dont know if that is something about TradingView, or if it can remain added once it was added in the first place.

Comment: I  was looking at the code you wrote.  It seems like the dots still want to keep plotting the signal constantly until the candle closes.  But what I need is for it to display the price of the very first signal it received and sticks to that price.  If you go to a 1 min chart and look at the dot, it keeps moving up and down with the candle as it keeps receiving the signals  and it doesn't just stick to the first received signal.  Therefore I dont know at what price I bought or sold at.  Super thank you for your time.

Comment: I think the false signals are due to live information. So for example when using close[1] this event has already happened, but using close is a live movement. So for example if you add this line to your code plot(hlc3) which is your src. You will see that it is live and moving with price action. So there will be at some points when you crossover is true in the moment that price action is moving within the timeframe you are using. But is finalized when that candle has closed.

Comment: The dot will keep moving until the hlc3 is completed and it is not completed until it is closed. I am sure I have seen a forum thread in reference to buy sell signals within StackOverflow to capture the first instance of the signal.

Comment: I will try using a different source and look around StackOverflow on how to capture the first instance of the signal.   Thank you for your help.